# Won't call on method in other class, Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

I am trying to learn Objective-C for iOS. i am currently following the "coding together" on iTunesU. Although i have got stuck since i can't get my controller to call on a method from another class. Can't find what i am doing wrong and thought that StackOverflow might have the solution to it!

The method "flipCardAtIndex" is the one that isn't working. I have debugged using nslog and from the method "flipCard" i get an output. But when i put in the implementation for flipCardAtIndex i don't get anything.. So my guess is that it never calls it... 
I have made the code a bit shorter so it is only the parts i think is important, this is controller:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLabel;
@property (nonatomic) int flipCount;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (CardMatchingGame *) game{
    if (_game) _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons     count]
                                                     usingDeck:[[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init]];
    return _game;
}

- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {

[self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
self.flipCount++;
[self updateUI];

}
```

And implementation:

```
- (void)flipCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US");
    Card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: Is `flipCardAtIndex` defined in CardMatchingGame.h?

Comment: BTW, when you say 'And implementation', I assume that code you're pulling is from your CardMatchingGame class?

Comment: @JamesBoutcher How the existence of the declaration would affect anything?

Comment: @JamesBoutcher yes "- (void)flipCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;"
and i am pulling it from that class.

Comment: I have tried making a new method just called test and tried to call on that but no response either. It's like it don't want to call anything from the CardMathingGame class....

Comment: @ZedIsDead - Okay, so when you say "you don't get anything", the only thing that can explain that is your self.game property isn't set. And I think then the problem is your "return the cache'd game instance" code is missing a "!" symbol.   (If game does NOT exist, then allocate a new one.)

Comment: Objective C lets you send messages to things that don't exist. Which can be a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix?

```
- (CardMatchingGame *) game{
    if (!_game) _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons        count] usingDeck:[[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init]];
    return _game;
}
```

Comment: Well, this question was answered ;-)